# Обрезка файла C++

Tags: c++, файлы, файловая-система

Есть у меня файл :

```
ifstream file;
```

Как обрезать файл на нужное количество байт?К примеру на 5.

Comment: imho никак, но можно попробовать `std::filesystem::resize_file`

Comment: Что-то не понимаю как это реализовать

Answer (score 1):

Обрезаем файл "c:/tmp/a.c" на 5 байт:

```
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    uintmax_t n = std::filesystem::file_size("c:/tmp/a.c");
    std::filesystem::resize_file("c:/tmp/a.c", n - 5);

    return 0;
}
```

работоспособность зависит, от того, какая версия у вас компилятора, на VS2015 например надо делать `std::experimental::filesystem`

Answer (score 0):

1. Открываете свой файл на чтение.
2. Открываете новый файл на запись.
3. Читаете из своего файла 5 байт.
4. Пишете эти 5 байт в файл на запись.
5. Закрываете оба файла.
6. Enjoy.

UPD1:

И да, читать и писать байты рекомендуется в бинарном режиме, если уж речь идет об обрезании файла с точностью до байта.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за ответы. Я сделал уже сам.
Вот как я сделал:

```
if (_sopen_s(&handle,c, _O_RDWR, _SH_DENYNO, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE) == 0)
 {
    d = _filelength(handle);
    cout << "Размер файла :" << d << endl;
    if (d > 10)
    {
        e = _chsize(handle, d - 5);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Файл меньше 10-ти байт" << endl;
    }
```